# How to push Mongoose object to array in Mongoose object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, push

I am trying to push a Mongoose object to an array within another Mongoose object, but what is stored in the array is only the ObjectId of the pushed Mongoose object.

The code is like this:

```
user.snippets.push(snippet)
```

If I console snippet, I see the whole object, but if I console the array user.snippets I only see an array of "new ObjectId([hexadecimal string])".

I have seen, and tried, code like

```
user.updateOne( {
     $push: { snippets: snippet }
} )
```

but I don't get it to work, and user.snippets.push seems more natural.

In the model for User, I declare the snippets array with

```
snippets: {
     type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
     ref: 'Snippet',
     required: false,
     trim: false,
     lowercase: true
}
```

Granted, it looks like an array, of ObjectIds, but in the model for Snippet, I have this code without problems:

```
author: {
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: 'User',
     required: true,
     trim: false,
     lowercase: false
}
```

I probably don't need lowercase and trim, as they are objects, but that's neither here nor there.

Comment: How is `snippets` declared in the `user` model? Please add that to your question.

Comment: @robertklep Thanks for the feedback. I have added the declaration, as well as the declaration of author in the Snippet model.

Comment: If you're using refs, you need to [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population).